# How can I connect two Dots with a line in SwiftUi?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

This is my code:

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        ForEach(0 ..< 4, id: \.self) { _ in // Index verwenden
            HStack {
                ConnectedCircles()
                CardView_beige {
                    HStack {
                        CardView_todo(title: "08:10 - 8:15", subtitle: "Mac Book sauber machen!", textlong: "15 min")
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
    .background(Color.white.ignoresSafeArea())
    .clipShape(
        .rect(
            topLeadingRadius: 25,
            bottomLeadingRadius: 0,
            bottomTrailingRadius: 0,
            topTrailingRadius: 25
        )
    )
}

struct VerticalLine: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY))
        return path
    }
}

struct ConnectedCircles: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            VerticalLine()
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 10)
            Circle()
                .strokeBorder(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)

            VerticalLine()
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 50)
        }
    }
}
```

These are my CardViews:

```
struct CardView_todo: View {
    var title: String
    var subtitle: String
    var textlong: String
    var time: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text(title)
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)
                        .padding(2)
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text(subtitle)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)
                        
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.leading, 2)
                
                HStack {
                    Text(textlong)
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)
                        .padding(2)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CardView_beige<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        content
            .padding()
            .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9490196078, green: 0.9019607843, blue: 0.8470588235, alpha: 1))) // Beige Hintergrundfarbe
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a list in SwiftUI where two points are connected by what is actually a dotted line.

I have managed to create a circle and a line, but I can't get the lines to connect, and I can't get the first circle of the list to have a line going upwards, for example.

Comment: Question 1) Do you want the line to go through the circle or do you want the circle to break up the line?

Question 2) Do you mean a line like ------- (referred to as a dashed line) or a line like --o--o-- when you say "dotted line"

Comment: @rayaantaneja 
1: The circle should interrupt the line.
2: In itself only ---, but a line goes only to one circle, there it is interrupted and then again a line to the next circle.

Comment: Okay last question then I can give you a solution: Can the lines above and below the circle be of equal length?

Comment: Can you add a picture what it should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dashed line makes this problem a little complicated. If you try to draw each link separately then you can sometimes see that the sizes of the dashes are different where the sections come together.

It works better if you have one continuous dashed line going from top to bottom. The circles can then simply be drawn over it. This can be achieved with just the `VerticalLine` shape and basic `Circle` shapes, `ConnectedCircles` is not needed.

Like this:

*EDIT:* Implementation changed from an `HStack` with negative padding on the main content to a `ZStack` with leading padding on the main content (it looks the same, but I think it's a bit cleaner).

*EDIT2:* Updated in response to comment to hide the dashed line above the first circle and below the last.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let nCards = 4
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {

                // The dashed line from top to bottom
                VerticalLine()
                    .stroke(style: .init(lineWidth: 4, dash: [7, 5]))
                    .frame(width: 60)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)

                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(0..<nCards, id: \.self) { index in // Index verwenden
                        HStack(spacing: 0) {
                            Circle()
                                .stroke(lineWidth: 4)
                                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .background(.white)

                            CardView_beige {
                                CardView_todo(title: "08:10 - 8:15", subtitle: "Mac Book sauber machen!", textlong: "15 min")
                            }
                            .padding()
                        }
                        // Align the circles with the dashed line
                        .padding(.leading, 15)

                        // Cover the dashed line above the first circle
                        // and below the last
                        .background {
                            if index == 0 {
                                VStack {
                                    Color.white
                                    Color.clear
                                }
                            } else if index == nCards - 1 {
                                VStack {
                                    Color.clear
                                    Color.white
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(Color.white.ignoresSafeArea())
            .clipShape(
                .rect(
                    topLeadingRadius: 25,
                    bottomLeadingRadius: 0,
                    bottomTrailingRadius: 0,
                    topTrailingRadius: 25
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Hope it's close to what you were wanting.

Comment: what does `dash: [7, 5]` do? I just put random values until I get something I like. You seemed to have chosen it deliberately. How did you come to those numbers?

Comment: @rayaantaneja The solid part is 7 pt long, the empty part is 5 pt long. Given that the line is stroked with a lineWidth of 4pt (that was given), I thought it worked quite well with these proportions.

Comment: This is a great solution. You could also use alignment guides instead of `.padding(.leading, -45)` to make it line up perfectly each time

Comment: @rayaantaneja I don't think an alignment guide will increase the content width. You will notice that the brown rectangles fill the remaining width (with padding around them). The negative padding makes the content wider.

Comment: @rayaantaneja Your comments got me thinking. I've edited the answer and changed the implementation from an ```HStack``` with negative padding on the main content to a ```ZStack``` with leading padding on the main content. It looks the same, but I think it's a bit cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: How can I make it so that the first dotted line at the top is gone and it only starts after the first todo with the lines, but the circle should remain there?

Comment: @JojoWho I thought of a better way of hiding the dashed lined above the first circle and below the last, answer updated. Instead of adding vertical padding to the line, use a split background behind the card row to cover it. This doesn't depend on the card having a certain height, it works for all heights of cards.

Comment: @JojoWho I see from your [latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77372901/20386264) that you have adopted the (earlier) code from this answer. So perhaps you could consider accepting and/or upvoting this answer? Thanks.

Comment: Oh yeah so sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

This is curious, I'm working on a very similar situation myself, needing to draw some lines connecting elements across rows in a list that's in a scroll area. I haven't finalised my own work yet, just did a proof of concept, enough to be confident that I can solve it when I need to cross that bridge. I will share the idea with you:

You could enclose the *contents* of the ScrollView with a ZStack and use it to superimpose another view on top of those contents. Use that view to draw your circle and lines easily in a single Shape/View. You should be able to get to a prototype of this with incorrectly placed circles and lines, in no time.

The only problem remaining is to get the right positioning of end points for your drawings. That can be done using GeometryReaders in the contents of the ScrollView, and passing that value up your view hierarchy using bindings.

Here's a simplified example spelling most of this out:

```swift
struct ConnectedCircles: View {
    @State private var startFrame: CGRect = .zero
    @State private var endFrame: CGRect = .zero
    
    struct Connector: Shape {
        var startFrame: CGRect
        var endFrame: CGRect
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            var path = Path()
            path.addEllipse(in: startFrame)
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: startFrame.midX, y: startFrame.midY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: endFrame.midX, y: endFrame.midY))
            path.addEllipse(in: endFrame)
            return path
        }
        
    }
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Label("1", systemImage: "globe")
                            .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                            .overlay {
                                GeometryReader { geo in
                                    Color.clear
                                        .onAppear {
                                            startFrame = geo.frame(in: .named("contents"))
                                        }
                                        .onChange(of: geo.frame(in: .named("contents"))) {
                                            startFrame = geo.frame(in: .named("contents"))
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        Text("First Row")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Label("2", systemImage: "globe")
                            .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                        Text("Second Row")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Label("3", systemImage: "globe")
                            .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                            .overlay {
                                GeometryReader { geo in
                                    Color.clear
                                        .onAppear {
                                            endFrame = geo.frame(in: .named("contents"))
                                        }
                                        .onChange(of: geo.frame(in: .named("contents"))) {
                                            endFrame = geo.frame(in: .named("contents"))
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        Text("Third Row")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Label("4", systemImage: "globe")
                            .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                        Text("Fourth Row")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                
                // This is the overlaid circles and lines
                Connector(startFrame: startFrame, endFrame: endFrame)
                    .stroke(.red, lineWidth: 2)
            }
            .coordinateSpace(name: "contents")
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this *greatly* simplifies the task of drawing the circles and lines, and also opens up all sorts of other overlaying possibilities. It also handles all sorts of surprises (eg device specific oddities, swiftUI changes) gracefully. I'd recommend you seriously consider this option.

Answer (score 0):

In the `LazyVStack` you have a `ForEach` which creates the rows for your list using `HStack`s. Your first step is to make sure each row has no spacing in-between them so your `ConnectedCircles` can look like they are connecting with each other. So:

**Step 1:**

```swift
LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {  // << here we set spacing to zero
    // ...
}
```

Then, make the HStack's size dependent on the `CardView` by adding the following modifier to the HStack:

**Step 2:**

```swift
HStack{
    ConnectedCircles()
    CardView_beige {
        HStack {
            CardView_todo(title: "08:10 - 8:15", subtitle: "Mac Book sauber machen!", textlong: "15 min")
        }
    }
    .padding()
}
.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)  // << we add this
```

Finally, remove the frame height you've set for the `VerticalLine` inside `ConnectedCircles` because you want those to take up as much space as they can:

**Step 3:**

```swift
struct ConnectedCircles: View {
    private let dashedStrokeStyle = StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 4, dash: [5])
    
    private let solidStrokeStyle = StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 4)
    
    var strokeStyle: StrokeStyle {
        solidStrokeStyle  // i personally like this one but substitute it for dashedStrokeStyle if you want that one
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            VerticalLine()
                .stroke(Color.blue, style: strokeStyle)
                .frame(width: 20)  // << removed height
            Circle()
                .strokeBorder(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            
            VerticalLine()
                .stroke(Color.blue, style: strokeStyle)
                .frame(width: 20)  // << removed height
            
        }
    }
}
```

And you're done!

I think this is what you were looking for. If it isn't then let me know in the comments :)